# python correlation coefficent

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

da=[]
outputFile = open ("core.txt","w")
f = open ('17059output.txt', "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for i in range (0,28):
   x = lines [6+(24*i):73+(24*i)]
   da.append(np.loadtxt('17059-2016-' + str(i+1) + '-' + str(i+4) + '.txt', 
   delimiter=",",usecols=2))
   np.array(x).astype(np.float)
   np.array(da).astype(np.float)
   print(x)
   print(da)
   print(np.corrcoef(x[i],da[i]))

   #print(scipy.stats.pearsonr(x[i],da[i]))
   #print(np.correlate(x[i],da[i],mode='valid'))
   #outputFile.write( str(i) + " - " + str(x) + "\n" )
```

Hello,

So I am trying to calculate da and x's correlation but I can't. Here is the problem;
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.

both x and da have 67 items, I have 744 rows in x and 28 different da with 67 items in them.

what I did basically; I cut the first 7th to 73rd rows in x and get one matrix for i=0 together with my first da '17059-2016-1-4.txt' dataset. Then, in x i get 31st to 97th rows and '17059-2016-2-5.txt'.
Both have 67 items, it is countable actually, but it doesn't work. I couldn't have found an answer on the internet.[python shell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQwlR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.array(x).astype(np.float)

rekt = []
for m in x:
    rekt.append(float(m));

np.array(da[i]).astype(np.float)

print(np.corrcoef(rekt,da[i]))
output = np.corrcoef(rekt,da[i])
```

this is the answer, btw i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `da` is initialized as an array and the following line is appending an item to it:

```
da.append(np.loadtxt('17059-2016-' + str(i+1) + '-' + str(i+4) + '.txt', delimiter=",",usecols=2))
```

So `da` is a list containing one item - an `array`.  On the other hand, `x` is an array containing a list of values. The output from your program shows this to be the case.

Therefore, I think your calculation of the coefficient should be done like this:

```
print(np.corrcoef(x, da[i]))
```